# Sass variables outputting question marks

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm using Sass and I have two variables in _base.scss:

```
$secondary-color:#0A864D;
$inner-radius: 3px;
```

They're getting used in _button.scss like:

```
 border-radius:$inner-radius;
 background:$secondary-color;
```

They come out in come out in chrome like the below, with question marks at the end as if there's an unencoded character:

```
border-radius: 3px�;
background: #0A864D �;
```

Can anyone cast any light on as to why? Thanks!

Comment: Did you verify that the special characters actually exist in the compiled CSS (looking in the inspector is useless)?  Did you try validating the compiled CSS?  Sass will typically choke on such characters.

Comment: I just checked the compiled (good thinking) and it has them too. I'm all new to Sass so have no idea on any gotchas.

Comment: UTF-8 issue perhaps...but it is odd.

Comment: If you copy/paste the code into something like [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/), does it still produce the characters?  What OS/Sass version are you using?

Comment: Thanks man, I think this helped me reach the answer. I pasted my _base.scss which holds my variables into sassmeister  and it's got little dots after each line. I think Coda has been adding in invisible characters. I turned them on to show and low and behold...how useful...